# Submit but not propagate django admin form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have an admin form that causes the page to refresh when a certain `select` field value changes. This, naturally, causes any unsaved data in the fields to be reset. Is it possible to somehow `POST` the current field data without having django try to validate/save it and just pass it back as the initial values of the form?

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the widget of one field depend on the value of another. Eg. if switched the `select` field from `2` to `3`, the page refreshes and the first field goes from being a `TextInput` to a `NumberInput`. Don't worry about the data validation in the dynamic field.

Comment: When you change the select does it trigger a POST or does it just updates the from via javascript/ajax?

Comment: I can make it do whatever I want, but right now just POST. I've thought about dynamically using javascript (too much of a pain) but not ajax. That might actually work. Thanks for the idea.